# ERROR: datanode can only be executed by harry

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop3

I want to start all (namenode and datanode) but when I used this command `start-all.sh` it returned:

`ERROR: datanode can only be executed by harry`

How to fix this?

Comment: Other than requiring `sudo su - harry`? What happens if you just run `hadoop namenode`?

Comment: it works fine but all the datanode do not run

Comment: Right. Then you run `hadoop datanode`

Comment: hmm now I have only 1 datanode which is my namenode as well? I dont want an standalone. I have 4 other slave nodes already installed hadoop. But It does not connect